# Python .replace() Error

Tags: python

In Python, I open a text file and read it line-by-line, and strip() the line before evaluating it.
When I evaluate the line, I have an if statement to check if the line is "random", and then puts a random number into a variable called genRandom. I have another line in my code that looks like this:

```
thisLine.replace("genRANDOM",genRandom) #Replace genRANDOM with the random number
```

On every line, it seems to work ok. In the input text file, I have a line that looks like this:

```
-genRANDOM
```

Whenever my script evaluates that line, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mass Storage\pythonscripts\TurnByTurn\execute.py", line 37, in <module>
    thisLine.replace("genRANDOM",genRandom) #Replace genRANDOM with the random number
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling `thisLine.replace` to replace the string `"genRANDOM"` with the number `genRandom`. That doesn't work, because it "expects a character buffer object" (such as a string), not a number.

Try `str(genRandom)` instead, to turn it into a string: `"4"` instead of `4`.

Also, you might want to name the variable something else; `genRandom` sounds like a function that generates a random number to me, not a random number that's been generated.

Comment: genRandom is a variable. As I said, it's a randomly generated number. str(genRandom()) worked, though, thanks!

Comment: @ghostmancer Yeah, sorry, I missed that part of the question originally; like I say in my edit, `genRandom` strongly sounds more like a function to me than a number. :)